# Как ограничить количество записей в таблице через phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, sql

Здравствуйте.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: делаю турнир, создал в phpmyadmin базу, создал в ней таблицу, теперь мне нужно, чтобы при записи на турнир записаться могло только 16 человек, не больше, но проблема в том, что в phpmyadmin не могу найти ограничения по таблицам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"можно ли сделать так, чтобы id не превышал значение 16 и всё" - нет. Средствами SQL так сделать нельзя (всякие искусственные ограничения типа триггеров мы не рассматриваем).

Если советы реализовать эту логику в коде приложения вы не принимаете, то все, что вам может дать mysql - это тип TINYINT SIGNED с диапазоном значений от -127 до 127

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать это [триггером](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8048494) на стороне базы или в пользовательском коде.

Лучший вариант - реализовывать эту логику в коде регистрации на турнир, одна таблица будет хранить всех участников всех турниров и тогда ограничивать таблицу максимумом - не получится.

Answer (score 0):

Да и не найдешь.

Средствами php делай проверку, а вообще ты изначально неправильно сделал структуру таблиц.

1 таблица только с турнирами
2 таблица с игроками
3 таблица связка игроков и турниров

тогда ты всегда знаешь из 3 таблицы сколько и с каком турнире у тебя игроков!

Comment: Эти таблицы у меня все есть, связки сделаны, но единственная проблема в том, что я не знаю, как сделать таблицу с турнирами максимум на 16 пользователей.

Comment: раз ты пишешь, что не знаешь, как сделать, значит таблиц, которые я написал, у тебя НЕТ!

или ты не понимаешь терминологии и не понимаешь, что такое таблица, запись и т.д., если у тебя есть таблицы, тогда что за глупый вопрос, что ты не знаешь как сделать таблицы???? Что за бред?

Comment: Скорее всего, я просто не могу донести суть вопроса, разъясню подробно: у меня есть таблица с пользователями, которые зарегистрировались на моём сайте, далее есть таблица с участниками турнира, в эту таблицу попадают только те пользователи, которые заполнили заявку для участия в турнире, теперь мне нужно сделать так, чтобы заявку могли подать не более 16 человек, если таблица заполнена, то 17-й человек уже не может подать заявку. Просто нужно сделать таблицу максимум на 16 пунктов, и я не знаю как.

Comment: Я дал ответ!
Нужно 3 таблицы! Все ведь просто, или ты на каждый турнир хочешь создавать отдельную таблицу????????????????????????????????????????????????????   ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: да господи, я просто спрашиваю. Допустим, есть колонка id, можно ли сделать так, чтобы id не превышал значение 16 и всё

Comment: нет нельзя.